# How do I make the function recognize the div I am clicking on?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I add an event listener to every div out of my gird of 100divs. In the function I should be passing as a parameter the square which is clicked. The problem is the click() function only recongnizes the last div (number 99).

```
function createBoard(){

 for(var i=0;i<width*height;i++){
 
  var square=document.createElement('div');
   grid.append(square);
   square.setAttribute('id',i);
   square.innerHTML=boardArray[i];
   squares.push(square);
   
   
    squares[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    click(square)
  })

 }//end for 

                   }//end func

createBoard();




function click(square){
var id=square.id;
console.log(id) //displays 99th 

}
```

Comment: why not just `square.addEventListener('click', function(e) {click(square)});`, and also, append your squares after setting the traits of the squares

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `const` instead of `var` when defining square. It's a bit of javascript voodoo, but what's happening is when you define a variable with `var` it gets put in the scope of the function it's in, so that every iteration of the loop updates the reference in the `square` variable. `const` and `let` get put in the scope of the block that they are defined in, so each iteration will get their own square.

You could bypass the issue by having the event listener use `event.target` instead of `square`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass `i` to the function if all you want is the id that you place on the div?